# Can not use "Open with Explorer" in library

Tags: open-with-explorer

After add my site to trusted site in IE browser, I still get the message below
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a bug. This is happened if you accessing a SharePoint 2013 site with cookie-based authentication enabled.

Apply the patches on your PC.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846960

Comment: can you give me a directly link to download this version of hotfix?

Comment: The direct-links are different, depends on your system. Read carefully on the Resolution section.

Comment: I can't find the way to download this @@

Comment: Then what is your operating system you were using when accessing SharePoint Document Library? What is the IE version?

Comment: IE11 . I'm using Microsoft Server 2012, Sharepoint 2013

Comment: As written on the site, "To resolve this issue in Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012, install update rollup 2903938, or install the hotfix that is described in this article". You should download the hotfix (KB2903938) in this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41252. Or simply just update Windows 2012 to the latest updates from Control Panel.

Comment: I'm sr, I just check my system, i'm using Window Server 2012 R2, is there any different???

Comment: Yes, the update that I've given to you only applies to Windows Server 2012 (non-R2). For R2 actually was never specified, but need to follow the same article. There are the other update rollout at the same time, though (Dec 2013).

Comment: But since for Windows Server 2012 R2 was never been mentioned anywhere, I suppose it is safe to update windows directly from Control Panel > Windows Update. make sure you've turn on the automatic updates. To make sure you have the latest, click on Check for Updates.